# How to run a executable as guest or limited user using java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, windows, security, privileges, processbuilder

Lets say I'm running as admin and I have a c executable as 'myProgram.exe'. I want to execute it using ProcessBuilder in my java program.

e.g.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myProgram.exe");
pb.start();
```

How can I execute 'myProgram.exe' as a less privileged user or guest user?

Why I want to do this?

Let say the exe (myProgram.exe) tries to delete some files that it should not delete or perform some other activities, Then running it under a less privileged user will not allow it do above things.

Basically I want to run this 'myProgram.exe' in a **jail** or with less privileges.

How can I execute 'myProgram.exe' as a less privileged user programmatically?

Comment: It should work as it is, unless your myProgram.exe requires admin privileges.

Comment: *"Basically i want to run this in a **jail.**"*  If your code could break out of jail, it would be a security bug that is quickly fixed.

Comment: @abhinav So you mean i should run my java program in less privileged user, so that all other it's child will also run under same privilege context?

Comment: Yes exactly. And so if now you exe needs admin privileges then it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need a `sand box` then.. It is an executable that executes another executable in an under-privileged settings..

see here: http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?StartCommandLine